# Can't use internet with RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+?

Tags: 14.04, realtek

I have a RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ in my ubuntu 14, but I can't use it.

And it is not a wireless drive, but a cable internet.

How can I use it?